# Equilibrium states that maximize diversity

Tags: combinatorics, dynamical-systems

In Bulgarian Solitaire, positions consist of stacks of some fixed number of "cards."  One position leads to the next by removing one card from each stack and creating a new stack from the collected cards.  If a triangular number $1+2+3+ \cdots + k$ of cards is used, one eventually reaches the "triangular position" with stacks of size $1, 2, \ldots, k$.  Otherwise, one arrives at a cycle of positions which are "nearly triangular," i.e., they can be made from the largest possible triangular position by adding single cards to some of the stacks.

In an informal sense, the equilibrium positions of Bulgarian Solitaire maximize the diversity of the stack sizes subject to a constraint on their height.  I'm curious if there are other dynamical systems which have this "flavor," in which equilibrium positions tend to diversify some characteristic (probably subject to some constraint).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, some examples:

- Consider some particles that repel each other in a confined space, e.g., a bunch of electrically negatively charged balls in a petri dish.
  In the equilibrium state, they maximise their distance, i.e., their locations are maximally diverse.
- Human society is based on [specialisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_of_labour):
  It is more efficient to have each individual focus their efforts on a single task instead of making everything themselves.
  So, the diversity of human skills and labour is maximised under certain constraints.
- In ecosystems, many species have their own ecological niche (i.e., they are focused on a specific prey, habitat, or similar), which is the outcome of the dynamical process of evolution.